# vee-validate multiple forms, scope - not working when using v-if but works with v-show

Tags: forms, vue.js, scope, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I am using vuetify and vee-validate in a vue app. I have 3 forms with input fields to validate. I use v-if to show each of the forms separately. i also use data-vv-scope="my_scope_name" with unique scope names for each of the forms. the forms are all in the same component.

if i navigate from another component to the component containing the forms and show form 1, for example, then the form validates as expected. if, from within the same component I hide form 1 and display form 2, and if it fails to validate then it does not display the error message. Similarly with form 3.

if i return to another component and then navigate back to the component containing the forms, then form 2 will validate as expected. Similarly with form 3.

so, to sum up. navigating between the forms from within the forms component, then only the first form validates as expected the others will not display the error message if they fail to validate.

each of the forms validate as expected if they are all displayed as the first form when navigating from another component.

now if i replace v-if with v-show, then all the forms validate as expected even when navigating to them from the component containing the forms.

is this normal behaviour or am i doing something wrong?